# One O/S, 2 Machines

Tags: grub2, kernel, laptop, ssd

quick question, Is it possible to share my Installation on my SSD between my main PC, and my laptop for when i go away, that way everything I need is still there, and dont have to worry about syncing files, programs, settings, etc. I tried this, but it has to reconfigure itself and then i have to go and reset all my driver settings each time i switch from one to the other, like is it possible to have say 2 kernels that i switch between depending on what im running off, and then select at grub when i boot up?

Comment: have you finally tried this? If yes -- share experience, I am also interested!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, but it might be a hassle in some cases.

If you just installed the base OS, using a text based log-in (no display drivers needed), make sure that the kernel has all the drivers for both systems (netwokr drivers etc) and that both use the same disk controller (e.g. both using SATA or eSATA) then this should work fine. Just pull the SSD from one machine, connect it to the other and boot.

However...

If you use a different disk layout then you might need to edit /etc/fstab every time (e.g. to change /dev/da0 with /dev/ad0, moving from IDE to SCSI or USB) or vice versa. You can solve that in several ways, e.g. with manually running a script (E.g. create a  *prep_next__boot_for_laptop.sh* **and** remember to run it), or you might get away with mounting devices based on their block ID.

If you also use different graphical settings, sound setting etc etc then it might be easier to just create two separate OS installations and share the home folder.

I prefer the last solution, though it means you have to keep two OS installations up to date,